# python if--elif-else usage and clarification

Tags: python

```
"""
This program presents a menu to the user and based upon the selection made
invokes already existing programs respectively.
"""
import sys

def get_numbers():
  """get the upper limit of numbers the user wishes to input"""
  limit = int(raw_input('Enter the upper limit: '))
  numbers = []

  # obtain the numbers from user and add them to list
  counter = 1
  while counter <= limit:
    numbers.append(int(raw_input('Enter number %d: ' % (counter))))
    counter += 1

  return numbers

def main():
  continue_loop = True
  while continue_loop:
    # display a menu for the user to choose
    print('1.Sum of numbers')
    print('2.Get average of numbers')
    print('X-quit')

    choice = raw_input('Choose between the following options:')

    # if choice made is to quit the application then do the same
    if choice == 'x' or 'X':
      continue_loop = False
      sys.exit(0)

    """elif choice == '1':  
         # invoke module to perform 'sum' and display it
         numbers = get_numbers()
         continue_loop = False
         print 'Ready to perform sum!'

       elif choice == '2':  
         # invoke module to perform 'average' and display it
         numbers = get_numbers()
         continue_loop = False
         print 'Ready to perform average!'"""

     else:
       continue_loop = False    
       print 'Invalid choice!'  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

My program processes only if I enter 'x' or 'X' as input. For other inputs the program just quits. I've commented out the elif parts and ran with only if and else clauses. Now a syntax error is thrown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your syntax error is coming from the `else:` line being too indented by one space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about the line `if choice == 'x' or 'X'`.

Correctly, it should be

`if choice == 'x' or choice == 'X'`

or simpler

`if choice in ('X', 'x')`

because the or operator expects boolean expressions on both sides.

The current solution is interpreted as follows:

`if (choice == 'x') or ('X')`

and you can clearly see that `'X'` does not return a boolean value.

Another solution would be of course to check whether if the uppercase letter equals 'X' or the lowercase letter equals 'x', which might look like that:

```
if choice.lower() == 'x':
    ...
```

Comment: `'X'` can be used in an if statement - but as it is a non-empty string it will evaluate to `True` and cause the statement `if choice =='x' or 'X'` to always be `True`.

Comment: Good observation, of course you are right, but I just simplified it to show him that it makes no sense in this context to evaluate a non-empty string.

Comment: Never know that or expects boolean on both sides. Thanks for explaining it more clearly as well as more pythonic.

Comment: No problem. As @DanielB explained before, 'or' doesn't strictly expect booleans on both sides, e.g. non-empty strings evaluate to 'True' too. I just wanted to show that this would be semantically false in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with your `if choice == 'x' or 'X':` part.To fix that change it to this:

```
if choice.lower() == 'x':
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice == 'x' or 'X':
```

is not doing what you think it's doing. What actually get's parsed is the following:

```
if (choice == 'x') or ('X'):
```

You probably want the following:

```
if choice == 'x' or choice == 'X':
```

which can be written as

```
if choice in ('x', 'X'):
```

Comment: that can be written as if choice in ('x', 'X')

Comment: or in this case, the even simpler `if choice.lower() == 'x':`

Comment: @bgporter. This is a more language independent choice of writing the expression. Thanks a lot for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

As the interpreter says, it is an IndentationError. The if statement on line 31 is indent by 4 spaces, while the corresponding else statement is indent by 5 spaces.

Comment: Thanks, since I copied code and pasted while asking question, I had to intend them and by mistake I would've added an additional space