# python if statement always

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, tkinter, python-3.3

So, I'm building up a simple game in Python to get more acquainted with the language, and couldn't find a way of searching if this was asked before. :P  Any-way, when this code block executes, I always end up with my "Position" being .y +10.  I've rearanged and checked a couple things, but feel I'm missing a quite basic part of what I would normally handle with a switch statement

```
mv = input('N,S,E,W?')

if mv == 'N' or 'n':
    Me.Position.Y += 10    
elif mv == 'E' or 'e':
    Me.Position.X += 10    
elif mv == 'W' or 'w':
    Me.Position.X -= 10    
elif mv == 'S' or 's':
    Me.Position.Y -= 10
else:
    print('Stand')
```

and then:

```
print('Lage: X:', Me.Position.X, ' Y:', Me.Position.Y, ' Z:', Me.Position.Z)
```

with no way of my other options being used.

THANKS!

Comment: This question came up a hundred times already, yet I still fail to find one to mark as duplicate. Stupid unsearchable issue.

Comment: @delnan - here you go... :) - [a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305089/issues-with-a-if-else-loop-in-python?rq=1) [few](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173108/python-if-elif-else-usage-and-clarification?rq=1) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329646/python-program-error-elif-else-if?rq=1) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348879/if-else-statment-not-following-the-elif-correctly?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `or` in your `if`-statement:

even if `mv == 'N'` evaluates to `False`, the non-empty string `'n'` evaluates to `True`, such that `mv == 'N' or 'n'` is always `True`.

What you want is:

```
if mv in ['n', 'N']:
    Me.Position.Y += 10
```

or even just:

```
if mv in 'nN':
    Me.Position.Y += 10
```

Comment: ah, so perhaps mv == 'N' or mv == 'n' would have been better, but thank you for the even more succinct answer :D

Answer (score 11):

Your code is being interpreted a little differently than what you expect. This line:

```
if mv == 'N' or 'n':
```

Is being interpreted as:

```
if (mv == 'N') or ('n'):
```

`'n'` is truthy, so your `if` statement will always be `True`. You have to be more explicit:

```
if mv == 'N' or mv == 'n':
```

Or use `in`:

```
if mv in ['N', 'n']:
```

Or use `.lower()`:

```
if mv.lower() == 'n':
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to check if your answer is in a tuple of possible answers, i.e.,

```
In [1]: mv in ('n', 'N')
Out[1]: True
```

tuple is preferred since it's immutable.

However, *if* you want to stick with your original code, you want to use

```
 if mv == 'N' or mv == 'n':
```

because given

```
 mv ='n'
```

then

```
In [2]: mv == 'n'
Out[2]: True

In [3]: mv == 'N'
Out[3]: False

In [4]: mv == 'N' or 'n'
Out[4]: 'n'
```

but

```
In [5]: mv == 'n' or mv == 'N'
Out[5]: True
```

which is what I believe your original intent was.